# If-Then Label Expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, vbscript, expression, if-statement

I'm trying to create a VB label expression on streets such that streets with an alternate name (ACS_ALIAS) will be labeled with the LABEL name and the alternate name in parentheses; streets with no alternate name will be labeled with the LABEL name only. Here is what I tried but to no avail:

```
Function FindLabel ( [LABEL], [ACS_ALIAS] )

if ( [ACS_ALIAS] <> <Null> ) then

FindLabel = ( [LABEL] & " (" & [ACS_ALIAS] & ")" )

elseif ( [ACS_ALIAS] = <Null> ) then

FindLabel = [LABEL]

end if

End Function
```

I can only think of some non-expression workarounds.

[image]

Comment: The function that you want to use to test if a value is <NULL> is IsNull https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278616.aspx.. *elseif ( isnull([ACS_ALIAS])) then* apart from that I don't see much wrong with it. IsNull only works with databases that support NULL (not shapefile) but you must be aware that empty strings are not NULL so the test has to be IsNull(field) then len(field)=0, if you go straight for len(field) it can fail if the value is NULL with an error message.

Answer (score 5):

Your conditional statements are not correct.  If you simply want to include a field in a label if it contains a value, then you can check if the field is null or blank.  If so, then just use [LABEL], if not, then label both fields as you mentioned.

```
Function FindLabel ( [LABEL], [ACS_ALIAS] )
    if IsNull([ACS_ALIAS]) OR Trim([ACS_ALIAS]) = "" then
        FindLabel = [LABEL]
    else
        FindLabel = [LABEL] & " (" & [ACS_ALIAS] & ")"
    end if
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Function FindLabel ( [NAME], [Label]  )

if ( [Label] = 1) then

 FindLabel =( [NAME])

end if

End Function
```

VB parser

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your answer to provide some more words (non-code) to describe your recommended solution.  Note that three backquotes will start/stop a code block, as will indenting four spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You need the second part of your argument in the If statements.  You've got the field name and then an operator, but no value.  [ACS_ALIAS] <> "" or [ACS_ALIAS] = "Something"

Without a value to compare the field value to the computer doesn't know what to compare to.

Like this:

```
Function FindLabel ( [LABEL], [ACS_ALIAS] )

if ( [ACS_ALIAS] <> **VALUE HERE**) then
FindLabel = ( [LABEL] & " (" & [ACS_ALIAS] & ")" )

elseif ( [ACS_ALIAS] = **VALUE HERE**) then

FindLabel = [LABEL]
end if

End Function
```