# If-then expression in Mapinfo label expressions

Tags: labeling, mapinfo, expression

Firstly this is similar to [If-Then Label Expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149373/if-then-label-expression) **BUT I need this for Mapinfo**.

So I want to do the following in Mapinfo in the label expression box in ver 12.

```sql
if RuralAdd='R':
 address=St_No + " ; " + LotPlan
else
 address=St_No
```

Is this possible? without creating a new column with this info using SQL.

===== @T_Bacon suggested I get the following but the lots with 0 St_No_1 still get a O in it. My code is

```
St_No_1+Left$(Chr$(13)+LOTPLAN, Len(LOTPLAN)*Int(Suf_No_1="R")*Int(St_No_1<>0))
```

output is
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this but it's not as easy as a simple If-Then unfortunately! The workaround here is to use the Int() function to generate a 1 or a 0 from a conditional statement and then use this as a multiplier for the length value of a string function. So, in your example case you could do this:

```sql
Left$(St_No_1, Len(St_No_1) * Int(St_No_1 <> 0)) + 
Left$(" ; " + LOTPLAN, Len(" ; " + LOTPLAN) * Int(RuralAdd = "R") * Int(St_No_1 <> 0))
```

Comment: Brilliant. One other complication that I found when I ran this. It should not put any label where the St_No is '0' or Null.. Can we add this condition. Would it be something like ...{ "R") * Int (St_No <> 0))... }?

Comment: Yes, that should do it if it's a numerical field. If it's a character column then you will need to change it to test for both "0" and "".

Comment: I tried the following but it still prints the 0. It doesn't print in the lots with null though. {St_No_1+Left$(" ; "+LOTPLAN, Len(" ; "+LOTPLAN)*Int(Suf_No_1="R") * Int (St_No_1<>0))}

Comment: Is the field St_No_1 a character field? If so you will need to put double quotations around the 0, eg. Int(St_No_1<> "0")

Comment: Nope St_No_1 is an integer.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem, I should have read through the original post again. Just to confirm that I'm right, you don't want ANY label on any records with an St_No_1 of 0? I've updated my answer to reflect that change, hopefully that's what you were after!